# Prolog - trying to build from initial knowledge, limit the infinite building

Tags: cryptography, prolog, logic, gnu

I'm trying to build a knowledge base that indicates messages an attacker is able to send to gain access to some secret data (my example uses a simplified version of the TLS protocol, meaning Client-Server-Certificate-CertificationAuthority-SessionKey).

Anyway, if one needs further explanation, please ask.

My problem:

Using the protocol, messages are sent, like this:

```
init(Init_1, Init_2, Init_3)
```

This message has 3 parameters.
Each of the parameters needs to have a **special format**.
For example:

```
nonce(Init_1)
publicKey(Init_2)
Init_3 = sign(SignedData, PrivateKey)
SignedData = [Id,PublicKey]
id(Id)
publicKey(PublicKey)
```

Also, to accept the message and send the following one a guard has to be checked:

```
ext(Init_3,Init_2) % meaning the signature can be extracted with the second parameter
extractedData(Init_3,Data) % Data is the extracted data from the signature
nth(2,Data,Init_2) % the second atom of the extracted data is the same as the second parameter
```

Most important, the attacker can only send messages with parameters that he knows.

```
knows(Init_1),
knows(Init_2),
knows(Init_3)
```

Okay, the attacker has the ability to gain knowledge. Basically, he can read all messages, so he knows the parameters at the beginning, which is his **initial knowledge**.
Example for a **default message**:

```
init(n_c , k_c , sign([c,k_c],k_c-1) )
```

leads to

```
knows(n_c,1) % the 1 is an artifact which may or may not be needed; tells the depth of the knowledge
knows(k_c,1)
knows(sign([c,k_c],k_c-1),1)
```

EDIT: I removed the long part about extracting Data from encrypted and/or signed data. Basically after collecting the default messages and asserting the initial knowledge from them, every decryptable and extractable data is added to the initial knowledge.

My problem now:
I want to build new messages by encrypting and signing the things in the initial knowledge.
This in itself is easy, but at the moment leads to infinite knowledge gain, because you can build such things as

```
enc(enc(enc(enc(enc(...(Data, Key)...)
```

But I want to restrict the message building to the special format up above.
In the example of init, I want to allow the building of

```
sign([Id,PublicKey],PrivateKey)
```

,but not something like

```
sign(sign([Id,PublicKey],PrivateKey),PrivateKey)
```

or worse things.

Last but not least, here are my message building or **parameter generation** rules:

```
knows([FirstData,SecondData],Depth) :-
Depth @> 1,
depth(SecondData,B), A is Depth - B,
knows(SecondData,B), knows(FirstData,A).

knows(enc(Data,Key),Depth) :-
Depth @> 1,
DepthMin1 is Depth - 1,
for(KeyDepth,1,DepthMin1),
isKey(Key),
Data \== enc(_, Key),
    knows(Key, KeyDepth),
knows(Data, DepthMin1).

knows(sign(Data,Signature),Depth) :-
Depth @> 1,
DepthMin1 is Depth - 1,
for(KeyDepth,1,DepthMin1),
isKey(Signature),
Data \== sign(_, Signature),
knows(Signature,KeyDepth),
knows(Data,DepthMin1).
```

Okay, this may be a bit much, but I don't know how much shorter I could have made this. If someone has a brilliant idea, please do tell.

EDIT:

Okay, maybe the programming problem was a bit hidden. So, basically, how do I limit generation of messages from the initial knowledge **knows(Data,1)** (using enc,sign and concatenation [,]) to a finite range (defined by the **special format** up above) (i.e. don't generate enc(enc(Data,Key),Key) if the message doesn't contain this template in the first place) ?

Comment: I find it difficult to see a programming question here.  You seem to be talking about a system for communication, not yet defined, as well as "a knowledge base that indicates messages an attacker is able to send..." that describes that system.  Consider stating a problem amenable to programming, with less focus on "I'm trying to..." and "I want to..." concepts.

Comment: Um...I may be too deep in the domain, but I'll try again, see the edit at the end of the post.

Comment: To avoid infinite repetition/nesting, don't you mean "don't generate enc(enc(Data,Key),Key) if the message **does** [already] contain this template"?

Answer (score 0):

you could define a "length" function for each message and then use it to get the shorter messages first.

for example, consider the following:

```
list([]).
list([0|T]):-list(T).
list([1|T]):-list(T).
```

this code recognises/produces lists of 0s and 1s.
should we just use list(L) we will just get zeroes:
[],[0],[0,0],[0,0,0]....

however, if we use length/2 for lists we will get what we want:

```
?- length(L,X), list(L).
L = [],
X = 0 ;
L = [0],
X = 1 ;
L = [1],
X = 1 ;
L = [0, 0],
X = 2 ;
L = [0, 1],
X = 2 ;
L = [1, 0],
X = 2 ;
L = [1, 1],
X = 2 ;
```

however, this wont get rid of the patterns you dont want; it will just make it appear later. in the example, if i didnt want the lists to have zeroes in the beginning length/2 is not good enough (still, it helps generating "meaningful" results)

the true fix is to create a pattern recogniser to filter and get only the good messages; this could be done with length too, just set the length to infinite when you discover that you have an illegal pattern.

one other solution is to reorganise your predicates.
in the example, if you put the 1 predicate first to get lists starting with 1 first.
or you could have used (more) layers of predicates like:
first_list([1|T]:-list(T).

just some ideas :)